# Odoo warning pop-up bug

Tags: python, odoo-10

In odoo10, I wrote a @api.onchange function on change of name which return warning popup if name already in database, so As I click on save button after giving input in name field then It returning a warning popup but also form saving on background which I don't want.

So, what is the actual problem here?
Please find attached screenshot below.
Thanks

[image]

Comment: Can you paste the code of your onchange method here, please?

Comment: `@api.onchange('displayname', 'firstname', 'lastname')
    @api.multi
    def check_duplicate_name(self):
     if self.name:
      contact = self.env['res.partner'].search([('name', '=', self.name)])
      if contact:
       return {
        'warning': {
         'title': 'Warning Message',
      'warning': 'Company/Contact name already exist.\nDo you want to continue?',
      }
        }`

Comment: Your problem is that Odoo lets you save the record after the warning is shown (although the name already exists in the database), isn't it?

Comment: My problem is that until the warning message is there the form should need to be in editable state.

Comment: What it's your question? Are you having any specific issue?

Comment: Needs to be using celery? I could provide you an example of doing that with Odoo and RabbitMQ usign just Pika

Comment: @AxelMendoza NO I just want to implement it with celery. I already tried rabbitMQ and removed. but thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If the problem is that Odoo lets you save the record after the warning is shown (although the name already exists in the database), you have to add a SQL constraint to your model, because the warning in the onchange method does not prevent users from storing the records.

```
_sql_constraints = [
    ('name_unique', 'unique(name)',
    'There is another record with the same name stored in the database!')
]
```

Of course you can keep your onchange warning in order to let the user know that if they keep that name, they're getting an error when saving the record.

Comment: thanks for answer but it raise a validation error and I want a warning only so, we can further proceed by clicking ok button.